# How would I get the other app's version from mac app

Tags: objective-c, macos

How would I get the other app's version. 
I can use [NSWorkspace fullPathForApplication:(NSString *)appName] to get app's path, can I get the app's info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's several ways you can accomplish this —  I usually take the shortest route using `NSBundle` in addition to `CFBundleversion`:

```
NSBundle *appBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:appPath];
NSString *bundleVersion = [appBundle objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the full path to the Application, you can read the `Contents/Info.plist` file and look at the `CFBundleShortVersionString` value.

Something like this:

```
NSString *appPath = [NSWorkspace fullPathForApplication:appName];
NSString *plistPath = [appPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Contents/Info.plist"];
NSDictionary *plist = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
NSString *version = plist[@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];
```